# How to get mouse coordinates with C + + QT?

Tags: c++, qt

```
void Window::acquire(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    pos_xy->setText(QString("coordinates：（%1,%2）").arg(event->pos().x()).arg(event->pos().y()));
}
```

Window is the inheritance class of QWidget, and the above code is a member function of this class。pos_xy is a QLineEdit *.

i want to get the coordinates of the mouse click,but i don't know how to call the acquire function when the mouse clicked.

Thanks in advance！

Comment: Is `event->globalPos()` the method you are looking for?

Comment: i  want  to know how to call them when the mouse click the Window

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be notified whenever the user clicks anywhere inside the window, you can implement that behavior using an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).  For example, you could create a class like this:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MouseWatcher : public QObject
{
public:
   MouseWatcher(QWidget * parent) : QObject(parent) {/* empty */}

   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
   {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
      {
         QMouseEvent * me = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
         QPointF windowPos = me->windowPos();
         printf("User clicked mouse at %f,%f\n", windowPos.x(), windowPos.y());
      }
      return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
   }
};
```

... and then install it as a filter on your window object, like this:

```
MyWindowObject * win = [...];
MouseWatcher * mw = new MouseWatcher(win);
win->installEventFilter(mw);
```

... and now it will print the window-relative mouse co-ordinates to stdout every time the user clicks on the window.

Comment: `Window` is already a subclass of `QWidget`. Wouldn't it be better to reimplement `QWidget::mousePressEvent` instead of creating an additional class for the event filter?

Comment: Depends on whether you need to be notified about any click in the window, or only about clicks directly on the window-widget itself (i.e. clicks that aren't located within any of the other widgets positioned inside the window).  If it's the latter, then overriding `mousePressEvent()` is sufficient.